# Handling an error when two queries are dependent of eachother and the second one fails?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, error-handling

Let's say I need to insert into one table and update another and those two things absolutely need to happen together. Example code:

```
$insert = query('INSERT INTO first_table');

if ($insert->successful) {
    $update = query('UPDATE second_table');

    if ($update->successful) {

    } else {
        log($update->errorMessage);
        // magically revert the effects from the first query?
        // store the query and try to execute it on the next request?
    }
}
```

Obviously I would log the error but all of the data would be out of sync/corrupted. What should I do in this case? Or am I doing the entire thing wrong and it shouldn't be in two queries?

Comment: You need to use `transactions` and if all goes well, `commit` else `rollback`

Comment: see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html , depending on the api you're using to connect your php script and the mysql server there might be "specialized" functions/methods for that, e.g. http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php

Comment: TRANSACTIONS (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) are your friends...

Answer (score 2):

You need transactions, additionally validate the state of start transaction and commit

```
//Start your transaction
$start = query('START TRANSACTION');
$insert = query('INSERT INTO first_table');

if ($insert->successful) {
    $update = query('UPDATE second_table');

    if ($update->successful) {
        //Do the changes
        $state = query('COMMIT');
    } else {
        //Undo changes
        $state = query('ROLLBACK');
        log($update->errorMessage);
        // magically revert the effects from the first query?
        // store the query and try to execute it on the next request?
    }
} else {
    //Undo changes
    $state = query('ROLLBACK');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start a transaction and commit only if you have success in the two queries

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html